# How to Load my Javascript file on a website that I have no access to its source

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm working on a monitoring system. It has a jquery-ui  graph! I want to edit that graph whenever it loads on my browser! and I do not have access to the source!
what can I do?

Comment: because of being client side, it seems it can be done!
but I could not find anything by searching google!

Comment: greasemonkey scripts, maybe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element)

Answer (score 0):

How do you not have access to the source if it's loading on your screen? I'm sure you could WireShark the data that's coming across to your computer if for some reason you're unable to do it through your web browser.

You should be able to save the page locally and work on it from your local PC. This is going to be best if you're going to make a lot of changes and want to keep your changes saved.

You can also use some developer tools that are built into your web browser. For example, with the Chrome Inspector (F12) you can right click under the Elements tab and Edit Attributes or Edit as HTML, and make changes to inline CSS and JS. Take a look under the Sources tab for included files.