# Javascript - Download other js and use it

Tags: javascript, html

I begin into the worl of Javascript and I try to do something :

- Go on my webpage
- A javascript sheet on this page download another .js from another website and launch function on it or use it

The code on localhost :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">

</div>

<script>
   update();
   setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text()},3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
function update(){
    httpGet("http://test.localhost/blabla.js")
}

function text(){
    return seeUpdate();
}

function httpGet(theUrl){
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
xmlHttp.send();
return xmlHttp;
}
```

on test.localhost :

blabla.js

```
function seeUpdate(){
    return "iajdiashdh";
}
```

So the test sheet use the blabla sheet.

How it is possible to this ? Because with my solution it doesn't work....

Thanks in advance,

Smooba

EDIT :

In fact, I found thanks to user2227904.

Here is the final version of the script :

```
function update(){
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.type = 'text/javascript';
imported.src = 'http://test.localhost/blabla.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
}
```

Thanks to everybody !

Smooba

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element

Comment: I dont see `seeUpdate()` defined anywhere are you missing some code? - nevermind its separate, I see it now.

Comment: It's defined at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the file using this code:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = '/path/to/imported/script';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

If this fails use third party library like jQuery

```
$.getScript('/path/to/imported/script.js', function()
{
  // script is now loaded and executed.
  // put your dependent JS here.
});
```

Comment: This is correct, JS scripts cannot reference other JS scripts without explicitly creating a new script element and injecting the file into it.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but it seems a much simpler approach is to include the script via a script tag, as in

```
<script src="http://test.localhost/blabla.js"></script>
```

But actually you probably should copy the script's contents so that you can include it from your own server. And since you're making the XHR call immediately, you might even include the said script's contents in your page for fast loading times.

Comment: While this is technically correct, based on the sample I assume there is a reason the user wants to explicitly call the js file from within another especially since the user demonstrates they know how to include js files by including the first one.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I wasn't sure if he knew he could include from a different server(!)

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to include like that. In fact, I want to choose the version of 'blabla' in the Javascript so I need to add it through Javascript. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to insert whatever you get from your xmlhttprequest into the page in a `<script>` tag, so it gets executed by the browser.