# append <script> tags with a function inside it to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a js function to body, but can't seem to do it.

I've tried:

```
$('body').append('<script>'+function PreviewImage2() {
                var oFReader = new FileReader();
                oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage2").files[0]);

                oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                    document.getElementById("uploadPreview2").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                };
            };+'</script>');
```

But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list


};+'
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element

Comment: Can you tell, why you need this. I mean you've already hard-coded the function to the file, there's nothing which would work differently within a new script tag. A new tag only would override the previous function with exactly the same function.

Comment: I keep adding file fields by js, and need previews for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').append('<script>'+function PreviewImage2() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage2").files[0]);

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                document.getElementById("uploadPreview2").src = oFREvent.target.result;
            };
        }+'</script>');
```

In your case try remove the ";" before the close script tag.

But, more correct variant is:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = 'function PreviewImage2() {' +
    'var oFReader = new FileReader();' +
    'oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage2").files[0]);' +
    'oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {' +
        'document.getElementById("uploadPreview2").src = oFREvent.target.result;' +
    '}' +
'}';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the `<script>` tag that you want to include, it's a behavior from the browser, you could do a little trick to avoid this.

First remove the semi-colon at the end of the function declaration, and replace the last `<script>` with a splitted one.

```
$('body').append('<script>'+function PreviewImage2() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage2").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview2").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
}+'</scrip'+'t>');
```

Comment: @hacketo, amazing, this works. I will accept this answer regardless, but before I close it off you might be willing to help me a little further. If I replace the name of the function with a var that holds the name, it doesn't work. so ...+function cpf {... doesn't work ( cpf holds the name). An idea why? And if just alert the cpf inside the code you gave me instead of the function, it alerts the proper function name! Why does it not work by replacing the function name?

Comment: @hacketo to make it clearer, $('body').append('<script>'+alert(cpf)+'</scrip'+'t>'); works, but ...$('body').append('<script>'+function cpf {... does not

Comment: if you want that the content of the variable `cpf` appear in the generated code you need to use a string literal notation, like in the second example of Maxim answer

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is because you are mixing strings and actual JavaScript code. To do something like this, you have to append a string. Try this:

```
$('body').append('<script>function PreviewImage2() { var oFReader = new FileReader(); oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage2").files[0]); oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) { document.getElementById("uploadPreview2").src = oFREvent.target.result; }; };</script>');
```

However, it looks to me like some of your logic is a bit off. It would be neater to append an actual script file, making sure your code stays readable.

Comment: error again, SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

$('body').append('<script>function PreviewImage2() {

Comment: Ah i see now, you cannot have newlines in JavaScript, my bad. I'll edit the answer accordingly.