# Inside HTML combining two javascript <script> requests into one

Tags: javascript, html

A system I am working with has a limitation of only supporting one script inclusion.
My script looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var TPR_customization = {
    id: "Thisismyscriptid",
    usecssplayer: false,
    startmuted: true,
    showmute: true,
    autoreplay: true,
    waterfallplaythrough: true,
    showclicktext: false,
    startclosehidden: false
} 
</script>

<script id="tprTag" type="text/javascript" src="
http://requiredbasejavascode.com/locationoffile/file.jsp"></script>
```

How can i combine this into one   call if i cannot edit the second portion ? I'd hate to use iframes.

Comment: You can add a script element with JavaScript.

Comment: you mind giving an example ?

Comment: This is too ambiguous, what is the system you are working on? If you are not able to say where in the document are the scripts placed? One in the body, one in the head or both? And why must you combine them, is it a necessity?

Comment: If you can only have 1 supporting script then I don't see how you can inject code into a file you cannot read/write to

Comment: @JulienEtienne Not certain why, this is how the system was designed and the current limitations of it.

Comment: @Adjit I was hoping that one could combine both since the first script is more for configuration. I cannot edit the file being called.

Comment: Dude you need to use some logic. Go though the system and figure out if it is custom made or something common via Googl-ing common words from the file names/ in the files. If it's a known framework/ CMS then you can locate where the this type of logic resides. 

This is what the script is: https://thirdpresence.atlassian.net/wiki/display/WIKI/In-banner+Ad+Tag+Parameters
That should help but you need to look though the pages, and you don't have access you need to ask for permission or whatever. No point in hacking everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TPR_customization = {
        id: "Thisismyscriptid",
        usecssplayer: false,
        startmuted: true,
        showmute: true,
        autoreplay: true,
        waterfallplaythrough: true,
        showclicktext: false,
        startclosehidden: false
    }

    var script  = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript"; // not needed for html5
    script.src  = "http://requiredbasejavascode.com/locationoffile/file.jsp";
    script.id   = "tprTag";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

**[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element)**