# jQuery Find and Append/Prepend to existing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, prepend

I have read many of the articles on using jquery to find and append. I have been successful at doing this on other projects, but mostly appending to a div element. I need to append to javascript on the page that unfortunately I don't have core access to.

Existing JS:

```
<div class="widget">
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var widget37 = new VideoWidget("VideoCanvas",                            
     "divVideoCanvas37", "DS37");
      widgetVideoCanvas37.SetWidth("630");
      widgetVideoCanvas37.SetHeight("355");
      widgetVideoCanvas37.SetVariable("isMute", "false");
      widgetVideoCanvas37.RenderWidget();
  </script>
 </div>
```

Before the RenderWidget, I need to add

```
 widgetVideoCanvas37.SetVariable("isAutoStart", "true");
```

I've tried something like this:

```
$( "widgetVideoCanvasDS37.RenderWidget()" ).prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

but it does appear to be working. Maybe prepend isn't the best way to do this. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This feels very sketchy overall.  Why don't you just set the variable with your script, instead of trying to append it to the DOM?

Comment: Just to clarify, there is a limitation from our core CMS. I have access to adding my own code that is called after their core code. I can't get their developers to fix what I want, as quick as I need it done, hence why I am trying to to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The element **would** be selected like `$('script').appened('blah');`
But i feel that that probably won't or shouldn't work.  That be a very large security flaw if i was able to run my own script locally to append JavaScript to the script element of another page that i don't have core access to.

Comment: Just posted a comment about this.

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element) to see if it can point you in the right direction.