# Why setting a variable in a iframe works in pure Javascript way but not in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to add a variable in a iframe, it works in Javascript way but it does not do what I want in Jquery way. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54tz7wn8/).

Pure javascript way:

```
var iframeDocument = $('#iframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
var scriptObject = iframeDocument.createElement("script");
scriptObject.type = "text/javascript";
scriptObject.innerHTML = "var variable=9;";
iframeDocument.body.appendChild(scriptObject);
```

Result is okay in console (variable is set and equals to 9 and iframe context) :

[image]

And when I try to change the value of the variable in JQuery:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').append($('<script type="text/javascript">').html('variable=10;'));
```

The variable is loaded in parent context and didn't change in iframe!
[image]

I know Javascript way is often better than Jquery way but I am simply wondering why this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/610995/1267304

Answer (score -2):

You are missing `</script>`, which by the way, you cant't inject like that.
Try this:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').append($('<script type="text/javascript"><\/script>').html('var variable=10;'));
```

Comment: `$('<tag>')` doesn't care about closing tags

Comment: But when it's appended it prints `</script>`, it's a way to force scaping, could also be: `$('#iframe').contents().find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript">var variable=10;<\/script>');`