# execute a javascript after page load is complete

Tags: javascript

how can I execute a java script after page load is complete

```
<script src="http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=503589&bid=1747907" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Do you mean you want to download this script src after page load?

Comment: its for an ads i want it load after page complete load

Comment: Put it at the bottom of the page?

Comment: i cant its an ads like adsense

Comment: thanks to who answered this question ^^ thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jquery, the below code might work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=503589&bid=1747907");
});
```

Wihtout Jquery

```
window.onload = function() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=503589&bid=1747907";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element );
}
```

Comment: shown in console : Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Answer (score 0):

This will run some javascript when the script file is loaded:

```
<script src="mysrc.js" onload="foo"></script>
<script>
  function foo() {
    console.log('Loaded script');
  }
</script>
```

This will run javascript when the entire page is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  console.log('Loaded page');
});
```

Comment: i want load that script when the page loaded not know if the js loaded

Comment: See the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Append the script load on ready event:

```
$(function(){
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=503589&bid=1747907");
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ndeLhkw9/

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery deferred.done () , see more [deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=503589&bid=1747907"></script>');
});
```

Comment: shown in console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I wish you could check this link for more info:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using jQuery:

```
function require(script) {
    $.ajax({
        url: script,
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,           // <-- This is the key
        success: function () {
            // all good...
        },
        error: function () {
            throw new Error("Could not load script " + script);
        }
    });
}
```

You can then use it in your code as you'd usually use an include:

```
require("http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=503589&bid=1747907");
```