# Is dynamic script injection in html blocking?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, inject

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element) it is clearly shown how to programmatically inject a new script in an HTML page.

What I'd like to ask, however, is if such injection is **blocking**, that is, it'll wait for the injected script to be loaded and executed before calling the next line.

For example

```
function inject(script_url) { ... }

// somewhere in the code
inject('/path/to/script.js');
func_in_script(); // <-- will "func_in_script" be defined at this point?
```

**EDIT:**

This is what I found out trying:

If I use native JS like

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
script.async = false; // !!!
script.defer = false; // !!!
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Then the functions in the loaded script are **not** immediately available after the call to `appendChild()`; however if I use jQuery like:

```
$('<script/>', {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    src: url,
    async: false,
    defer: false
}).appendTo('head');
```

It works as I'd like it to.

Comment: __No__, If you are loading them asynchronously..

Comment: And can I force the loading to be blocking?

Comment: Yes..Using `async : false`

Comment: `$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success,
  async : false
});`