# How to execute server returned javascript on client

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make an ajax call to a server and the server returns javascript and jquery code such as

```
$('someclass').html('<form id='billform'>......</>');
$('#billform').submit();
```

How do I execute this on the client side?

Comment: `$('#billform').submit();` hope this is the problem and the use `id="billform"`

Comment: Technically you can run any arbitrary code using `eval` in practice, this is a really bad idea in most situations and suggests that you are probably not doing something correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put that code inside a script tag and append it to the body
This procedure is described best here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/611016/4202031

**However**, it is not recommendet to simply execute some javascript which is loaded via ajax. I would recommend to work with events that would trigger this code which is on your page already.

```
$.get('/sumUrl', function(data) {
  switch(data.action) {
    case 'event1':
      //do sth.
      break
    case 'event2':
      // do sth. else
      break
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the code as a function in your static page, then call the function from the returned ajax call. A small example:

on your static page:

```
function submitmyform(formcontents)
{
   $("someclass").html(formcontents);
   $("#billform").submit();
}
```

on your ajax success method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getform",
    method: "POST",
    data: $(".myform").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        submitmyform(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your id in quotation marks, and as id instead `$` use `#`

```
$('someclass').html('<form id="billform"></>');
$('#billform').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval function from javascript to execute the scritp which are string
e.g.

```
eval('alert("Hello!")');
```

I your case

```
eval('$(".someclass").html("<form id="billform">......</>")');
eval('$("#billform").submit()');
```