# How to append <script></script> to <div> and execute it?

Tags: javascript

i have this code and this is not working

```
<script>
    dialogFun();
            function dialogFun(){

                var code="<div style='font-size: 12px' id='dialog'><script src='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xyz.js'> </script><div id='jwplyr'>Loading the player...</div><script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('jwplyr').setup({'file': 'http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/xyz-lusPHdHK.mp4','image':'http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/xyz-320.jpg'});</script></div>";


                console.log(code);
                $( "body" ).append( code );
            }
</script>
```

this is not working

Comment: What mean it's not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element)

Comment: Notice you are using jQuery have you made sure you added the jQuery lib correctly ? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: What do mean "not working"?
You simply need to ESCAPE "/" of closing tags `<\/script>`

Comment: Your code is correct as I have tested it is appending  the script to the body but it is not able to access `https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xyz.js` so in console it is showing ***jwplayer is not defined***. Try to give the correct url

Comment: @Kyle Only escaping `</script>` is necessary, because `</script>` terminates the beginning `<script>`, even if it’s within a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESCAPE the "/" of closing tags

```
<script>
    dialogFun();
            function dialogFun(){

                var code = "<div style='font-size: 12px' id='dialog'>"+
                "<script src='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xyz.js'><\/script>"+
                "<div id='jwplyr'>Loading the player...</div>"+
                "<script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('jwplyr').setup({'file': 'http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/xyz-lusPHdHK.mp4','image':'http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/xyz-320.jpg'});<\/script><\/div>";


                console.log(code);
                $( "body" ).append( code );
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Should you always escape closing tags or is this a special case ?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers Only escaping `</script>` is necessary, because `</script>` terminates the beginning `<script>`, even if it’s within a string.

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers for script tags are required