# How to add script element and ins programmatically inside div?

Tags: javascript

**QUESTION:**

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
var code = (<ins>...</ins><script>...</script>)

document.getElementById("rightScroll").append(code);
```

What is the correct syntax ?

EDIT: Of course this syntax is incorrect, that's why I am asking for a solution here.

---

**SITUATION:**

The element will be added to `rightScroll` every time the user scrolls `100vh`

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what it is that you want to do, but from what you've described this feels like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element)

Comment: @gyre Lol, that's literally the last question I checked before I asked my question. That method does not work in my case.

Comment: @SamAxe My bad, let me correct this.

Comment: @Coder1000 Post what you tried. We can't tell what you're doing wrong otherwise.

Comment: Why do you want to add another `<script>` element every time the user scrolls? Is there a change to the script each time?

Comment: It would be better if the script just defined a function. You would load it once, and call the function every time the user scrolls 100vh.

Comment: @Barmar I already have said function. I just need a way to append an adsense ad every time the user scrolls (question edited)

Comment: @j08691 Question updated

Comment: You said you tried the method in the question that @gyre linked to. Show your code that uses that method.

Comment: `.append()` is not a DOM method, it's a jQuery method.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I had the jquery tag in there, I had forgotten.

Comment: @Barmar I did not try the method per se, since I wouldn't know how to include both the <script> and <ins> with that method :/

Comment: You don't have to do anything special for `<ins>`, do that normally. Use the method in the other question to add the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the elements as dom elements:

```
var ins = document.createElement("ins");
ins.className = 'adsbygoogle';
ins.style = 'display:block;width:300px;height:600px;margin-bottom: 20px;';
var attClient = document.createAttribute('data-ad-client');
attClient.value = '...';
ins.setAttributeNode(attClient);
var attSlot = document.createAttribute('data-ad-slot');
attSlot.value = '...';
ins.setAttributeNode(attSlot);

var myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
myScript.innerHTML = '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});';

var rightScroll = document.getElementById("rightAdScroll");
rightScroll.appendChild(ins);
rightScroll.appendChild(myScript);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9tdn2qcd/1/

Comment: Thank you :D I was surprised it took so long for someone to answer  correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo on the `getElementById` method, and the string you are building is not in quotes.  I've roughly quoted the string you've provided, but it will likely need extra attention where your `...` code is.

```
var code = "<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"" +
         "style=\"display:block;width:300px;height:600px;margin-bottom: 20px;\"" +
         "data-ad-client=\"...\"" +
         "data-ad-slot=\"...\"></ins>" +
         "<script>" +
         "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});" +
         "</script>";

document.getElementById("rightAdScroll").append(code);
//                   ^^ was missing "Id"
```

This will only work though if you have an `append` method on your DOM element.  `append` is a jQuery method but it doesn't appear that you are using it directly in this case.

I'd recommend either making 2 calls to:

```
var myElem = document.getElementById("rightAdScroll");
myElem.appendChild(insTag);
myElem.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

or use jQuery (if you have it loaded already):

```
$('#rightAdScroll').append(code)
document.getElementById("rightAdScroll").append(code);
```

Comment: As @Barmar pointed out in the comments, `append` is not a valid DOM method.

Comment: sorry, hit enter before adding that clarification