# angular 4 _ how can I change dynamically google map api key

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular7, angular2-services

I use google map API in my application like this :

import url with api key in index.html :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>
```

and in component declare google like this :

```
declare let google: any;
```

and use it in component like this :

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), this.mapProp);
```

How can I change API key dynamically that exist in the index.html ?

Comment: you should really blot out your api key, so people don't take it

Comment: you dont need to use declare let, just use declare. why would you want to change your api key?

Comment: this is a fake api key and just for show

Comment: good to know, glad you didnt through it up there

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: sorry , not yet :(

Comment: plz update if you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, you can add the script tag directly to the DOM.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey';
$("#someElement").append( script );
```

It will load the new code when you add it.

Code is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/611016