# how to inject jQuery and use it in the same bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I can successfully inject jQuery to a page with the following bookmarklet:

```
javascript: void((function(doc) {
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        var script_jQuery = document.createElement('script');
        script_jQuery.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
        Node.prototype.appendChild.call(document.body, script_jQuery);
        console.log('jQuery included ^_^');
    } else {
        console.log('jQuery already included ...');
    }
})(document));
```

Is there a way to use the just injected jQuery within the same bookmarklet? I tried putting `console.log(jQuery.toString())` after the apend part, but it didn't work. It seems to me that jQuery is only available for using after the bookmarklet finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onload` callback of the new script element to initialize your own jQuery code

```js
(function(doc) {

  function doStuff() {
    console.log('jQuery version ', $.fn.jquery, ' loaded')
    $('h1').text('Updated Title').css('color', 'red');
  }

  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var script_jQuery = document.createElement('script');
    script_jQuery.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';

    // call doStuff() after jQuery.js loads
    script_jQuery.onload = doStuff;

    doc.body.appendChild(script_jQuery);
    console.log('script_jQuery appended to body');
    
  } else {
    console.log('jQuery already included ...');
    // initialize your code using existing version
    doStuff();
  }
})(document)
```

```html
<h1>Blank</h1>
```

Comment: In Firefox, this always says "$.fn is undefined" when I run it on non jQuery websites. But when I type $.fn in browser console afterwards, it is defined... 
Does Firefox's onload not work properly?

Comment: @Needsmorejpeg If you are having  problem you should ask a new question and include all the specifics